# assumed-role is not authorized to perform: route53:ListHostZonesByDomain; Adding a Route53 Policy to a CodePipeline CodeBuildAction's Assumed Rule

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, amazon-route53, aws-cdk, aws-codebuild

My goal is to create a website at subdomain.mydomain.com pointing to a CloudFront CDN distributing a Lambda running Express that's rendering an S3 website. I'm using AWS CDK to do this.

I have an error that says

`[Error at /plants-domain] User: arn:aws:sts::413025517373:assumed-role/plants-pipeline-BuildCDKRole0DCEDB8F-1BHVX6Z6H5X0H/AWSCodeBuild-39a582bf-8b89-447e-a6b4-b7f7f13c9db1 is not authorized to perform: route53:ListHostedZonesByName`

It means:

- `[Error at /plants-domain]` - error in the stack called `plants-domain`
- `User: arn:aws:sts::1234567890:assumed-role/plants-pipeline-BuildCDKRole0DCEDB8F-1BHVX6Z6H5X0H/AWSCodeBuild-39a582bf-8b89-447e-a6b4-b7f7f13c9db` is the ARN of the Assumed Role associated with my object in the `plants-pipeline` executing `route53.HostedZone.fromLookup()` (but which object is it??)
- `is not authorized to perform: route53:ListHostedZonesByName` the Assumed Role needs additional Route53 permissions

I believe this policy will permit the object in question to lookup the Hosted Zone:

```js
const listHostZonesByNamePolicy = new IAM.PolicyStatement({
  actions: ['route53:ListHostedZonesByName'],
  resources: ['*'],
  effect: IAM.Effect.ALLOW,
});
```

The code using `Route53.HostedZone.fromLookup()` is in the first stack `domain.ts`. My other stack consumes the `domain.ts` template using `CodePipelineAction.CloudFormationCreateUpdateStackAction` (see below)

`domain.ts`

```js
// The addition of this zone lookup broke CDK
const zone = route53.HostedZone.fromLookup(this, 'baseZone', {
  domainName: 'domain.com',
});

// Distribution I'd like to point my subdomain.domain.com to
const distribution = new CloudFront.CloudFrontWebDistribution(this, 'website-cdn', {
// more stuff goes here
});


// Create the subdomain aRecord pointing to my distribution
const aRecord = new route53.ARecord(this, 'aliasRecord', {
  zone: zone,
  recordName: 'subdomain',
  target: route53.RecordTarget.fromAlias(new targets.CloudFrontTarget(distribution)),
});
```

`pipeline.ts`

```js
const pipeline = new CodePipeline.Pipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
  pipelineName: props.name,
  restartExecutionOnUpdate: false,
});

// My solution to the missing AssumedRole synth error: Create a Role, add the missing Policy to it (and the Pipeline, just in case)
const buildRole = new IAM.Role(this, 'BuildRole', {
  assumedBy: new IAM.ServicePrincipal('codebuild.amazonaws.com'),
  path: '/',
});

const listHostZonesByNamePolicy = new IAM.PolicyStatement({
  actions: ['route53:ListHostedZonesByName'],
  resources: ['*'],
  effect: IAM.Effect.ALLOW,
});


buildRole.addToPrincipalPolicy(listHostZonesByNamePolicy);

pipeline.addStage({
  // This is the action that fails, when it calls `cdk synth`
  stageName: 'Build',
  actions: [
    new CodePipelineAction.CodeBuildAction({
      actionName: 'CDK',
      project: new CodeBuild.PipelineProject(this, 'BuildCDK', {
        projectName: 'CDK',
        buildSpec: CodeBuild.BuildSpec.fromSourceFilename('./aws/buildspecs/cdk.yml'),
        role: buildRole, // this didn't work
      }),
      input: outputSources,
      outputs: [outputCDK],
      runOrder: 10,
      role: buildRole, // this didn't work
    }),
    new CodePipelineAction.CodeBuildAction({
       actionName: 'Assets',
      // other stuff
    }),
    new CodePipelineAction.CodeBuildAction({
      actionName: 'Render',
      // other stuff
    }),
  ]
})

pipeline.addStage({
  stageName: 'Deploy',
  actions: [
    // This is the action calling the compiled domain stack template
    new CodePipelineAction.CloudFormationCreateUpdateStackAction({
      actionName: 'Domain',
      templatePath: outputCDK.atPath(`${props.name}-domain.template.json`),
      stackName: `${props.name}-domain`,
      adminPermissions: true,
      runOrder: 50,
      role: buildRole, // this didn't work
    }),
    // other actions
  ]
});
```

With the above configuration, unfortunately, I still receive the same error:

`[Error at /plants-domain] User: arn:aws:sts::413025517373:assumed-role/plants-pipeline-BuildCDKRole0DCEDB8F-1BHVX6Z6H5X0H/AWSCodeBuild-957b18fb-909d-4e22-94f0-9aa6281ddb2d is not authorized to perform: route53:ListHostedZonesByName`

With the Assumed Role ARN, is it possible to track down the object missing permissions? Is there another way to solve my IAM/AssumedUser role problem?

Comment: What is `plants-pipeline-BuildCDKRole0DCEDB8F` role?

Comment: In `IAM` -> `Roles` -> `plants-pipeline-BuildCDKRole0DCEDB8F` -> `Trust Relationships` -> `Trusted entities`: `codebuild.amazonaws.com`

How can I see the resources that are using this Role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer from the official doco: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/pipelines-readme.html#context-lookups

TLDR:
pipeline by default cannot do lookups -> 2 options:

- synth on dev machine (make sure a dev has permissions)
- add policy for lookups

```html
new CodePipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
  synth: new CodeBuildStep('Synth', {
    input: // ...input...
    commands: [
      // Commands to load cdk.context.json from somewhere here
      '...',
      'npm ci',
      'npm run build',
      'npx cdk synth',
      // Commands to store cdk.context.json back here
      '...',
    ],
    rolePolicyStatements: [
      new iam.PolicyStatement({
        actions: ['sts:AssumeRole'],
        resources: ['*'],
        conditions: {
          StringEquals: {
            'iam:ResourceTag/aws-cdk:bootstrap-role': 'lookup',
          },
        },
      }),
    ],
  }),
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error, the pipeline role (and it would work at the stage or action...)

By default [a new role is being created for the pipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-codepipeline.Pipeline.html#role):

> role?
>
> Type: IRole (optional, default: a new IAM role will be created.)

The IAM role to be assumed by this Pipeline.

Instead, when you are constructing your pipeline add the `buildRole` there:

```js
const pipeline = new CodePipeline.Pipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
  pipelineName: props.name,
  restartExecutionOnUpdate: false,
  role: buildRole
});
```

Based on your pipeline you never assigned the role to the relevant stage action [according to the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-codepipeline-actions.CloudFormationCreateUpdateStackAction.html#deploymentrole):

```js
pipeline.addStage({
  stageName: 'Deploy',
  actions: [
    // This is the action calling the compiled domain stack template
    new CodePipelineAction.CloudFormationCreateUpdateStackAction({
      ...
      role: buildRole, // this didn't work
    }),
    // other actions
  ]
});
```

Should be:

```js
pipeline.addStage({
  stageName: 'Deploy',
  actions: [
    // This is the action calling the compiled domain stack template
    new CodePipelineAction.CloudFormationCreateUpdateStackAction({
      ....
      deploymentRole: buildRole
    }),
  ]
});
```

Why is it `deploymentRole` instead of just `role`, no one knows.